# Stitching Image to form perfect panorama

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have taken image from google street view covering FOV=90 in four directions. with headings set at 0, 90, 180 and 270 degree and then merged them in this sequence Back-Left-Front-Right.

Although FOV 90 X 4 =360 but panorama is not continuous.And joints are clearly visible. Can anyone help me in this as how can i get a perfect panorama?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of the official Google Site for creating a Photo Sphere and upload your 360 degree panoramic image to be Viewable in Google+ and Android. Please note that you can also submit this Photo Sphere image to Google Maps. Here is the link

https://photo-sphere.appspot.com/